# Angular js ng-repeat and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested `ng-repeat`. I want to arrange order of the inside list by dynamic options.

i.e. the `sort_option` value is from `$scope` variable getting dynamically. This will give all inside `ul` list are in sorted order, but I want to sort only one list inside the loop.

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat='itemsli in mylists.lists'>
 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: sort_option | filter: {due_date_time : current_date_time}">
  {{item.name}}
 </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the line like this, add `: true` at the end of filter

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: sort_option | filter: {due_date_time : current_date_time}: true ">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly

but I created [sample code](https://plnkr.co/edit/GTRqULWfj0I7ZoF9HgbB?p=preview) like yours and seem like it works fine

the lists are

```
$scope.firstLists = [{id: 2},{id: 1},{id: 3}];
$scope.secondLists = [{id: 2},{id: 1},{id: 3}];
```

with

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat='itemsli in firstLists'>
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in secondLists | orderBy: 'id'">
     {{item.id}} of {{itemsli.id}}
     </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

and the result is

```
1 of 2
2 of 2
3 of 2
1 of 1
2 of 1
3 of 1
1 of 3
2 of 3
3 of 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on [Farzad Salimi Jazi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40716484):

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat='lists in mylists.lists'>
<md-button ng-click="sortby_cards('vote', lists)">Sort by votes</md-button>
<md-button ng-click="sortby_cards('attachment_count', lists)">Sort by Attachments
</md-button>

 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: list.sort_option | filter: {due_date_time : current_date_time}">
  {{item.name}}
 </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.sortby_cards = function(sort_value,list){
    $scope.sort_option = sort_value;
    $scope.sort_index_val = index_val;
    list.sort_option = sort_value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this kind of nested ng-repeat?

```
var app = angular.module('soApp', []);
app.controller('soController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.sortby_cards = function (sort_value) {
        console.log(sort_value);
        $scope.sort_option = sort_value;
    };
    $scope.firstLists = [{name: "def", vote: 2}, {name: "ret", vote: 1}, {name: "ghj", vote: 3}];
    $scope.secondLists = [{name: "pqr", vote: 2, attachment_count: 1},
        {name: "abc", vote: 1, attachment_count: 3},
        {name: "xyz", vote: 3, attachment_count: 2}];
});
```